Certbot Failed to parse: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
I recently updated my python to implement FastAPI, but i don't realize and not sure it actually affected the certbot.
How should i revert the python or fix this issue, after i tried to reinstall the certbot using snap it still resulted the same thing.
root@thevantive:/etc/apache2/sites-available# certbot certonly --apache
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
An unexpected error occurred:
requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Failed to parse: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.

